# Access database Query Enter Parameter Value not working

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvvaY.jpg) query `where` statement in an access database:

```
WHERE (((IIf([MinOfDueDayMin]<0,0,Int([MinOfDueDayMin]/7)+1))<[EnterValue]) AND ((tblEquipment.Retired)=False))
```

The intent is to ask the user for a value and when the formula `----((IIf([MinOfDueDayMin]<0,0,Int([MinOfDueDayMin]/7)+1))----`  is less than the user input when prompted with `[EnterValue]`.  If I use a number like 52 instead of the `[EnterValue]` I get the correct results but when I keep the `[EnterValue]` I get the prompt and when I enter 52 I get results that are not less than 52. I actually get all the results as if the criteria was not there.  However when I put in 10 when prompted instead of 52 I get the correct results.

The formula is in my results

```
IIf([MinOfDueDayMin]<0,0,Int([MinOfDueDayMin]/7)+1) AS Wks
```

so it displays the results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the user input to the numeric value. Use the `Val()` function for this:

```
IIf([MinOfDueDayMin]<0,0,Int([MinOfDueDayMin]/7)+1))<Val([EnterValue])
```

You can also specify the data type for the parameter. [This article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-c2806d3d-d500-45a8-8507-ec6af351b6ed) shows you how:

> To specify the data type for parameters in a query:
>
> 1. With the query open in Design view, on the Design tab, in the Show/Hide group, click Parameters.
> 2. In the Query Parameters box, in the Parameter column, enter the prompt for each parameter you want to specify a data type for. Make
>      sure that each parameter matches the prompt that you used in the
>      Criteria row of the query design grid.
> 3. In the Data Type column, select the data type for each parameter.

Comment: Thank you. I did figure it out on my own.  Adding a number works too and then it treats it as a value.